# Nuxt Auth extend / modify Google Social

Tags: nuxt.js, django-allauth, nuxt-auth, dj-rest-auth

I've set up social authentication using dj-rest-auth / django allauth. The endpoint expects this info as JSON:
[image]

Unfortunately it seems to me like Nuxt Auth assumes the backend should extract the information from the URL, although it sends it as a POST-request.
So what happens is:
I click on continue with Google > Nuxt auth pushes me to google > Google pushes me to my callback URL with all the information present in the URL.. and Nuxt Auth grabs that URL and just sends it off as is.

[image]

So I'm left with two options:

1. Do I attempt to modify the backend, which feels fairly troublesome.
2. Do I somehow override Nuxt Auth? I'm fairly clueless here.

The docs talk about creating custom schemes:
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/scheme

But from that point I really **can't figure out how to customize the actual post-request being made**. Help would be appreciated.

MY NUXT.CONFIG.JS:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/register',
      logout: false,
      // callback: '/login',
      home: '/bevakning'
    },
    strategies: {
      google: {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        codeChallengeMethod: '',
        responseType: 'code',
        endpoints: {
          token: 'http://localhost:8000/social-login/google/',
          userInfo: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/user/'
        },
        // withCredentials: true,
      },
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'key',
          type: 'Token ',
          maxAge: 86400 * 120
        },
        user: {
          // using property: false means it will use the entire json response as user and not just one variable.
          property: false
          // property: 'email'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/dj-rest-auth/login/ ',
            method: 'post',
            // propertyName: 'auth_token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/dj-rest-auth/logout/',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/dj-rest-auth/user/',
            method: 'get',
          }
        },
        // tokenRequired: true,
        // tokenType: 'Token ',
        // globalToken: true,
        autoFetchUser: true,
      }
    }
  },
```

EDIT: Solved the issue I had, which unironically was caused by Axios overriding the nuxt auth method. I realized something was off when the content-type was set to JSON, yet the body was sent as if it was x-www-urlencoded.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was related to me adding an application/json header globally with Axios.
axios: {
// extra config e.g
baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
timeout: 30,
headers: {
common: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
Accept: "application/json",
},
}
},

This caused the x-www-urlencoded format of the Nuxt Auth POST request to be wrongly interpreted.